# zsh alias expansion

Tags: zsh, alias, autocomplete

Is it possible to configure zsh to expand global aliases during tab completion?  For example, I have the common aliases:

```
alias -g '...'='../..'
alias -g '....'='../../..'
```

but when I type for example `cd .../some<tab>` it won't expand to `cd .../something` or `cd ../../something`.  Consequently, I frequently won't use these handy aliases because I can't tab complete where I want to go.

Answer (score 6):

Try looking up **zsh abbreviations**. They allow you to enter an "abbreviation" which automatically gets replaced with its full form when you hit a magic key such as space. So you can create one which changes `...<SPACE>` to `../..`.

For example, this is what you need in your profile:

```
typeset -A abbrevs
abbrevs=(
        "..." "../.."
        "...." "../../.."        
)

#create aliases for the abbrevs too
for abbr in ${(k)abbrevs}; do
   alias -g $abbr="${abbrevs[$abbr]}"
done

my-expand-abbrev() {
    local MATCH
    LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
    LBUFFER+=${abbrevs[$MATCH]:-$MATCH}
    zle self-insert
}

zle -N my-expand-abbrev    
bindkey " " my-expand-abbrev 
bindkey -M isearch " " self-insert
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a [custom ZLE widget](https://github.com/nicoulaj/dotfiles/blob/7a37acd50401a235d6dec6327cd5b2224d704b72/zsh/comp.d/ZLE/rationalize-dots) for this, just drop it somewhere in a directory in `$fpath`. You can then configure it [this way](https://github.com/nicoulaj/dotfiles/blob/7a37acd50401a235d6dec6327cd5b2224d704b72/zsh/conf.d/04_ZLE.zsh#L39).

Comment: links are broken and their content is missing from this answer